# Bind DataGrid to List<Dictionary<string,string>>

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm loading my datagrid columns dynamically as the number of columns may vary in runtime. The list of column names are retrieved in the `ProdCatList`.I want to simulate adding a single row into my QuotationDG Datagrid.

Here's how I add my columns:

```
 foreach (ProductCategory ProdCat in ProdCatList)
 {
      DataGridColumn ProdCatColumn = new DataGridTextColumn {Binding = new Binding(ProdCat.Name)};
      ProdCatColumn.Header = ProdCat.Name;
       QuotationDG.Columns.Add(ProdCatColumn);
 }
```

This is how I'm trying to add the dummy row:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> mydictlist = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> mydict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i=0; i<ProdCatList.Count; i++)
{

    mydict.Add(ProdCatList[i].Name, ProdCatList[i].Name);
  }
  mydictlist.Add(mydict);

 QuotationDG.ItemsSource = mydictlist;
}
```

For the first code, the columns display correctly, but for the second code a row is added to the DataGrid but the Names (in the dictionary values) are not displayed and all columns are blank. 
How can I fix this code to show the data in the added row?

Answer (score 0):

your mydist type will use same object if you define it outside the loop

```
for (int i=0; i<ProdCatList.Count; i++)
{
   Dictionary<string, string> mydict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    mydict.Add(ProdCatList[i].Name, ProdCatList[i].Name);
}
  mydictlist.Add(mydict);
```

Comment: Yes, but this is what I need to be doing, to add several keys and values to the same mydict object. This way I can represent my row using mydict (with many columns)